# Como passar o valor de uma variável para um outro documento HTML em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Em um arquivo HTML eu possuo uma variável criada em JavaScript chamada `vidadps` e eu quero passar o seu valor para um outro documento HTML. Como eu posso fazer isso em JavaScript ?

**Dentro do HTML inicial:**

```html
<script>
    var vidainit = 100
    var dano = 20
    var vidadps = vidainit - dano
</script>
```

**Dentro do outro documento HTML:**

```html
<script>
    function obterValor(){
        // Função para retornar o valor do HTML anterior
    }
    
    var vidadps = obterValor()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível. Você pode passar vários valores na URL do seu outro documento html utilizando os separadores `?` ou `#`.

Caso opte por usar o `#`, você deve obter os valores no outro documento pelo `location.hash` e caso opte usar `?`, você deve obter os valores pelo `location.search`. Veja esse exemplo abaixo:

**Dentro do arquivo index.html:**

```html
<script>
    var valor = 345;
    location.assign("outroHTML.html#" + valor);
</script>
```

**Dentro do arquivo outroHTML.html:**

```html
<script>
    var valor = location.hash.split("#")[1];
    console.log(valor);
</script>
```

O que o `location.hash` e o `location.search` fazem é retornar os valores passados na URL como uma string. No exemplo eu utilizei o `split("#")` porque ele devolve os valores com os separadores.

A mesma coisa aconteceria também se eu utilizasse o `search`. Veja como ficaria:

```html
<script>
    var valor = location.search.split("?")[1];
    console.log(valor);
</script>
```

Como o retorno disso é uma String, depois de ter obtido o valor você deverá convertê-lo para inteiro. E lembre-se que é sempre bom verificar que tipo de valor foi passado na URL antes de tomar alguma ação.

Comment: Nossa Muito Obrigado